# CodeIgniter query building best practice

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have two tables called 'Users' and 'Books' where each user can have multiple books taken at any given moment. There is another table called 'User_Book' which holds 'id's from both tables. Now I am in need of a screen where I list all users along with the books they have. What is the way to achieve this? Do I need to query first

```
select * from Users;
```

and while executing for loop of each user again query..

```
select * from User_Book left join Books on UserBook.Book = Book.id;
```

and in an inner loop print all books? Is this the right way to do it? Is there any way CodeIgniter provides so I can just get a 'Users' array where each array element (user) will hold a sub array which is 'Books' by the user ?

I mean the following output (rough version)...

```
 { 'Name' => 'John', 'Age' => 20, 'Books' => array('Book1', 'Book3') }, 
 { 'Name' => 'Barbie', 'Age' => 15, 'Books' => array('Book1', 'Book2') },
 { 'Name' => 'Fazil', 'Age' => 25, 'Books' => array('Book1') }
```

Looking for best way to implement it. Kindly advise.

Comment: Why you don't use many-to-many relation between Users and Books? If you use many-to-many relation if you select user from Users table you also will get all books belong to him.

Comment: @Wolen - thank you for helping me out. i still can query like that starting from 'User_Book' table and left join user table and book table in a single query i do get that. But the result set will have user info multiple times for the users who have more than one book. That does sound not perfect way for me though i can write condition at php end to show it only once.

Comment: many-to-many relation fixs this problem. That's the point why I mentioned about this way. You select user and you get all books belong to him. No problem with multiple records with that same user.